# Plugin: Events manager - Next and previous event

Tags: events, previous, next

I'm trying to get a navigation in the events of event manager

the next/previous post links work but they are ordered by creation date 
instead of event date.

How could it be possible to change this?

Answer (score 1):

The function WordPress ultimately uses for this is [get_adjacent_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post), which has filters that allow you to modify the query directly. You'd have to modify the `JOIN`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses to join the post meta table and order by your custom field.

Another option is the [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/) plugin.

Comment: To use get_adjacent_post, you would basically need to write your own function, there is no built in way to use it. You can just copy the function from http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1088 and then paste that into your functions.php file? I am just learning about this myself

Comment: @westondeboer - you don't have to access the function directly, you can add your filters to it and then call `next_post_link` as you normally would, which will then call `get_adjacent_post`, applying your filters to the query.